# Gradual memory allocation strategy

Tags: c, memory-management

For didactic purposes, I am working on a program that reads a string (array of chars) from standard input. The goal is to allow the program to sequentially increase the memory allocated according to the dimension of the input. I would like your opinion on my approach.

I thought I could allocate one byte of space one by one, for every reading cycle needed. Clearly, it does not work. How could I approach this problem? Is it even worth trying?

Thank you for your patience and support!

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<ctype.h>

int main(){
        char *q;
        int flag = 1, j = 0;
        printf("\n\nNow let's go for a word of undefined lenght. Type it:\n\n");
        do{
                q++ = calloc(1, sizeof(char));
                flag = ((q[j] = getchar()) != 0); #Until it is valid.
                ++j;
        }while(flag);
     return 0;
}
```

Comment: First, read the documentation for `getchar()`.   It returns `EOF` when done, not zero.   Second `q++ = calloc(1, sizeof(char)` does not grow a buffer.   It allocates (and leaks) a single and then increments the pointer that `calloc()` returns.

Comment: Thanks @Peter, that is a really valuable suggestion. I did not think with such a perspective.

Comment: You should start by taking as example the code from the manpage of sscanf.

Comment: Look up realloc(). You want start with an allocation of 1, then realloc to 2, 3, 4 .. etc as each byte comes in. (There are other optimisations, but this is a start).

Comment: `getchar()` returns value of type `int`. Never ever use `char` to store the return value of `getchar()`.

Comment: your goal isn't clear. when does the program completes reading input ? On the first occurrence of `'\n'` or at `EOF`. In both the cases read @worice answer. Its better to allocate a buffer of fixed size probably 4K if its the first case.

Answer (score 1):

Reading the entire input at once is typically wrong.

The standard approach is to get a buffer of few kilobytes and read + process the data in chunks of that size, overwriting previously read data which is now useless.

In rare cases where you need to have the entire thing in ram and are reading from a regular file, you can fstat the file to get its size and allocate accordingly. If the file is big (megabytes in size), you should mmap.

Finally, in extremely rare case where you need to read stuff up and you can't know the size in advance, the way is to realloc *doubling* the size each time. i.e. size *= 2; new = realloc(p, size); p = new; ....

Comment: In the last case, I recommend `newsize = 3 * oldsize / 2 + 10;` instead of your `newsize = 2 * oldsize;`

Comment: yea, approaches differ to an extent and have to be adjusted for the case at hand. the gist though is most of the time you don't want to read the data upfront, but if you do, you want to reallocate with big jumps